# Delete those pesky ".DS_Store" files

Tags: code-golf, file-system

If you use OS X then you might be familiar with the infamous hidden ".DS_Store" files that are produced as a result of using Finder.

The challenge is to write code that will go through the entire file system and delete any file named ".DS_Store".

Classic code golf - shortest code wins.

---

**Clarifications:**

- The code does *not* need to delete any .DS_Store files that require superuser; assume no such files exist.
- The code should *only* delete the relevant .DS_Store files and nothing else.

Comment: And again a chameleon question.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn The latest edit should have been self-evident, I would assume. I added it for the sake of completeness. But I appreciate the clever answer, nonetheless!

Comment: @Joey — Transpose the question into the military domain — for example, hmm… the military of the USA, at random ^^ . And replace “file named ".DS_Store"” with “person to kill”. And you will see that the requirement “only” is far from being evident.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions which ask for malicious code are off topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/) and the described task counts as malicious per [our guidelines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9767/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## zsh, 19

```
rm -f /**/.DS_Store
```

(Make that 16 if it's ok to leave out `-f`.)

Answer (score 12):

#### Bash*, <strike>40</strike> 30

```
find / -name .DS_Store -delete
```

```
find / -name .DS_Store -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This should handle it (not very golfed, not.to.mention marvelously slow).
Bash seems right because we don't have to deal with any "import system" nonsense. If you want to require execution in any environment, add 4 chars for `bash` and 1 for a line feed.

*any shell I guess, just can't get out of the habit assuming the bourne again shell is the only one.

Comment: Bash is exactly the right tool for that.

Comment: What kind of `find` has OS X? With GNU `find` is even shorter: `find / -name .DS_Store -delete`.

Comment: Umm, find does have `-delete` yes. I guess that I assumed it wouldn't act as the `-f` option does with `rm`. After a test, it is most satisfactory--Cheers.

Comment: Subject to “Argument list too long” error and requires either `bash` 4 or newer with `globstar` shell option turned on, or `zsh`: `rm /**/.DS_Store`.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48` is what I am currently using courtesy of osx.6

Comment: You're not doing anything bash-specific, so it could as well be sh.

Comment: It removed my `.DS_Store` directory where I had important stuff.

Comment: @KonradBorowski Why would you name a directory `.DS_Store`, and expect a program explicitly designed to delete things named `.DS_Store` to not delete that directory?

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby: <s>38</s> 33 characters

```ruby
File.delete *Dir['/**/.DS_Store']
```

Comment: `Dir[...]` is a shortcut for `Dir.glob(...)`, this will save you 5 chars.

Comment: Argh! I knew there is a shorter way, but I searched for it in `Kernel`. Thank you, @padde.

Answer (score 2):

## fish, 16

```
rm /**/.DS_Store
```

(Make that 19 if `-f` is required to delete `.DS_Store` in read-only directories.)

Answer (score 0):

## Shell, 25

```
locate .DS_Store|xargs rm
```

Requires working `locate` database.

Comment: Also requires paths without whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 80 bytes

```python
import os
d='.DS_Store'
for r,_,f in os.walk('/'):
 if d in f:os.remove(r+'/'+d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mCvFVl3PJTg@uCS/KFWdKy2/SKFIJ14nTSEzDyirV56Yk62hrq@uacWlkJmmkAISTrMCShSl5uaXpWoUaQMltVM0//8HAA)

By no means competable, but just for the sake of it :)

Answer (score 0):

## CMD, 17

```
del/s "/.DS_Store
```

Pretty straight-forward.

`/s` is required for searching within subdirectories as well.
`"` is used to escape the `/` char which would otherwise be interpreted as an (invalid) argument.

Answer (score -1):

## find, 38

The previus `find` solution is plain wrong: it's mean to delete everything named `.DS_Store` including directory, links, special file etc.

But:

```
find / -type f -name .DS_Store -delete
```

it's the minimal solution using `find`.

**DISCLAMER**: I strongly advice against really using this solution on a real *nix box: trying to delete something recursively from `/` is a very **bad** idea. You are warned.

**EDIT** :

If the differences among files, directorys, links (hard and symbolic), named pipes, sockets, special files, pseudo-file systems is not clear to you, I suggest to google some of this unknown terms. You'll be surprise, wiser, and less prone to (catstrofic) errors.

**EDIT2** :
Even more relevant : the OP wrote "The code should only delete the relevant .DS_Store files and nothing else." : so, if someone care to read the **boring** requirements, all solutions that remove more than this files hare funny, smart, ect. but *wrong*.

Comment: The previous `find` solution is correct. The question says “delete any file named ".DS_Store"”. So no special requirement based on file type.

Comment: @ manatwork : nonsense: a file is a different thing from a directory. Along your twisted line, the best solution is still rm -rf /

Comment: and thanks for downvote me: you guys do it because you dont know the difference between a file and a directory or it's just because I'm unpleasant to you ?

Comment: @DavAlPi: Your solution won't delete named pipes, sockets, directories, and other special files. `.DS_Store` files are normally normal files though, so here's a +1 from me.

Comment: @ Evan: In a unix filesystem everthing is a file except directories, named pipe, sockets, and other **special files** that are *NOT* files. Try to google some of this unknown terms, you'll be surprise (and wiser).

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention file system links (hard and symbolic). But certainly by now you have googled etc. etc. :)

Comment: Ohh, you did not google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Comment: Ohh, and an other thing: In code golf the goal is to get the shortest solution, so if you can save a few chars by trating the requirements in your favor, well, so be it. You could save 8 chars by treating everything as file, like unix does. PS: where was the surprise? The fact that some people deny the basic UNIX principe?

Comment: Dear Johannes, the OP wrote "The code should only delete the relevant .DS_Store files and nothing else." : The requirements rules.

Comment: johannes, have a nice day :-)

Comment: Now I got a [better answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12005/8401) , something that everyone here can understand.